# How to correctly parse closing parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to parse all brackets in strings with following command:

```
\((.+)\)
```

but no clue how I should rewrite the command for next string:

> (You Gotta) Fight For Your Right (to Party)

I want to extract both **(You Gotta)** and **(to Party)**

Comment: please clarify: do you want to be able to match both of those sets instead of the match just matching the entire string?

Comment: `parse closing parentheses` - As soon as you mention _closing_ you have a problem. That requires _open_. These don't exist in a vacuum, requires balanced text. Can python do recursion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a negated character class instead of `.+` and then use `re.findall()` :

```
>>> s="(You Gotta) Fight For Your Right (to Party)"
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)',s)
['You Gotta', 'to Party']
```

Note that, here your regex will match every thing between an open parenthesis and an close parenthesis which would be contains the following part :

```
(You Gotta) Fight For Your Right (to Party)
^-------this part will be matched --------^
```

But by use of negated character class `[^()]+` it will match every thing between parenthesis except parenthesis literals.Which makes your regex engine stops at each closing bracket.

```
(You Gotta) Fight For Your Right (to Party)
^         ^                      ^        ^
```

Comment: Any ideas how we can extract text inside parenthesis including `(` and `)`?

Comment: @SpanishBoy If you want to get the parenthesis as well you can remove the capture group.So change the  `([^()]+)` to `[^()]+`