# How to add closing parentheses when there are additional parentheses inside

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a "parser" which has to replace a keyword with another keyword

```
trim(<something>)  --> ltrim(rtrim(<something>))
```

I am using python regular expressions.
The main issue is since in the `<something>` part there can be additional parentheses which makes forming a regex very difficult to me. Simply adding a `?` to make it non-greedy doesn't really work, and putting greedy the regex will match with the parentheses at the end of the file 200 lines down.
From the start I assume someone else had this issue, and I found these two questions.

[How to correctly parse closing parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638327/how-to-correctly-parse-closing-parentheses)

[How to add a missing closing parenthesis to a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400960/how-to-add-a-missing-closing-parenthesis-to-a-string-in-python)

But neither help in my case,
my code so far:

```
def run(path):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
        with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
            s = f.read()
        s = s.replace("trim","ltrim(rtrim" )
        text = s
        text = re.sub(r'(\(.+(?!\))\b)', r"\1)", text)
        return text
```

The code just adds closing `)` without including the text in between even though I places a `+` in my regex which should mean at least one appearance of any char.

Like this

`trim(p_name)` becomes `ltrim(rtrim()p_name)`

I need it to be `ltrim(rtrim(p_name))`

Comment: It is not quite clear. Do you mean you have no parentheses in `trim(<something>)`? If no, then you just need `return re.sub(r'\btrim\(([^()]*)\)', r'ltrim(rtrim(\1))', text)`

Comment: Regex isn’t good for parsing things like arithmetic expressions where there can be nested things like ( ), or XML with nested < > - you’re much more likely to succeed using a proper parser..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there are sometime parentheses  inside the <something>. Example trim(str(p_name))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex works when there is a single word in the parethesis, which is great, already an improvement,  thank you very much, but when there are nested () thats where nothing happening, and thats what im struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match recursive patterns with built-in Python `re`, so you will have to `pip install regex` to install the PyPi regex module and use

```py
return regex.sub(r'\btrim(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))', r'ltrim(r\g<0>)', text) )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9HTQT/1).

*Details*:

- `\btrim` - matches a whole word `trim`
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 pattern (recursed)
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

The replacement is `ltrim(r\g<0>)`: `ltrim(r` + the whole match + `)`.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEEbhfU8xdJP5rRTFnag9iLHFQqgBk4bpCBW8e6Tt9vHx0ldfYzzl7EMaRUnc4OZC3ax0pVLFB55UOHXxGRxQFkl8VN5cPX16FmP71Vnm5nxvGY@q@nFzBHYWMHsS816B2OFyuC1l@YOQ8x8):

```py
import regex
text = "trim(str(p_name))"
print( regex.sub(r'\btrim(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))', r'ltrim(r\g<0>)', text) )
## => ltrim(rtrim(str(p_name)))
```